# HighStock: Loading series data asynchronously as needed

Tags: highcharts

I want to display multiple years of historical stock data in a HighChart. The json data size for all the years is 5mb, why I want to avoid loading all at once. Especially because most users will only need the last 6 month.

I would like to fetch the first 6 months initially. If the user zooms out or "moves" backwards in time I would like to load the whole data. Has someone a recipe for this? What is the starting point? Are there any HighChart events I could listen to, to get notified when the user zooms out or moves?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for the **[`xAxis.events.setExtremes`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.setExtremes)** event.

You will need to combine it with [`Series.addPoint(Object options, [Boolean redraw], [Boolean shift], [Mixed animation])`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series.addPoint%28%29) inside a loop with the redraw option as false inside the it and explicitly call [`Chart.redraw()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Chart.redraw%28%29) after looping all the newly added points.

You may also need to look @ **[`navigator.series`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.series)** since your navigator series may require to be different from the actual series

Comment: Thanks. How can I know when I need to load more data?

Comment: xAxis.events.setExtremes is the event that you want to handle, it will give you the new min and max, you can keep a tab of the time range for which you already have data by storing it in js and then fetch the data that is not there.

Comment: Okay! Is there a way to show the user that loading is going on?

Comment: I highly recommend checking out the Highcharts API reference, its really useful with some handly jsFiddle examples. To answer your question [`Chart.showLoading()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Chart.showLoading%28%29) and [`Chart.hideLoading()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Chart.hideLoading%28%29) can be called explicitly to show and hide such indicators, @Erik

Comment: I know, but if I call Chart.showLoading() the data series are still shown. I'll try, anyway